# Kubernetes Ingress Path only works with /

Tags: kubernetes

I have configured a kubernetes ingress service but it only works when the path is /

I have tried all manner of different values for the path including:

```
/*
/servicea
/servicea/
/servicea/*
```

This is my ingress configuration (that works)

```
- apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    name: boardingservice
    annotations:
      ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  spec:
    rules:
    - host: my.url.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: servicea-nodeport
            servicePort: 80
```

This is my nodeport service

```
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    name: servicea-nodeport
  spec:
    type: NodePort
    ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8081
      nodePort: 30124
    selector:
      app: servicea
```

And this is my deployment

```
- apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    name: servicea
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    template:
      metadata:
        name: ervicea
        labels:
          app: servicea
      spec: 
        containers:
        - image: 350329402011.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/servicea
          name: servicea
          ports: 
          - containerPort: 8080
            protocol: TCP              
        - image: 350329402011.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/serviceb
          name: serviceab
          ports: 
          - containerPort: 8081
            protocol: TCP
```

If the path is / then I can do this http://my.url.com/api/ping
but as I will have multiple services I want to do this: http://my.url.com/servicea/api/ping but when I set the path to /servicea I get a 404.

I am running kubernetes on AWS with an ingress-nginx ingress controller

Any idea?

Answer (score 9):

You are not using kubernetes Pods as they are intended to be used. [A Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/)

> it contains one or more application containers which are relatively tightly coupled — in a pre-container world, they would have executed on the same physical or virtual machine.

If you have two applications, `servicea` and `serviceb`, they should be running on different Pods: one pod for `servicea` and another one for `serviceb`. This has many benefits: you can deploy them separately, scale them independently, etc.
As the [docs say](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-overview/#understanding-pods)

> A Pod represents a unit of deployment: a single instance of an application in Kubernetes, which might consist of either a single container or a small number of containers that are tightly coupled and that share resources.

These Pods can be created using `Deployments`, as you were already doing. That's fine and recommended.

Once you have the `Deployments` running, you'd create a different `Service` that would balance traffic between all the `Pod`s for a given `Deployment`.

And finally, you want to hit `servicea` or `serviceb` depending on the request URL. That can be done with `Ingress`, as you were trying, but [mapping each path to different services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#simple-fanout). For example

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my.url.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /servicea
        backend:
          serviceName: servicea
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /serviceb
        backend:
          serviceName: serviceb
          servicePort: 80
```

That way, requests going to your ingress controller using the /servicea path would be served by the Pods behind the `servicea` Service. And requests going to your ingress controller using the /serviceb path would be served by the Pods behind the `serviceb` Service.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You are correct that I was not using containers in the recommend way but in this case, the containers represent a single whole that must be scaled together and need to run togther. As it happens, the error I was having was not my Kubernetes configuration but  my application, it just took me a while to figure out.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone reading this, my configuration was correct (even though unorthodox, as pointed out by fiunchinho), the error was in my Spring Boot applications, that were running in the containers. I needed to change the context paths to match the Ingress path - I could, of course, have changed the @GetMapping and @PostMapping methods in my Spring Controller, but I opted to change the context path.

Comment: "the error was in my Spring Boot" what if i try to connect to not my application? how can i modify root path?